# Unknown property 'String.FirstName'

Tags: salesforce, visualforce, apex

**Error: Unknown property 'String.FirstName__c'**
I am trying to develop a simple Registration page which includes three columns named as FirstName, LastName and ContactNumber.
Could anyone tell me the line where i have done mistake.

```
<apex:page Controller="Reg">

        <apex:form>

        <apex:pageBlock title="Registration Edit"  mode="edit">
      <apex:pageBlockButtons location="both">
          <apex:commandButton value="save" action="{!Save}"/>
          <apex:commandButton value="cancel" action="{!Cancel}"/>

          <apex:commandButton value="addRow" action="{!addRowMethod}" rerender="anyName"/>
          <apex:commandButton value="removeRow" action="{!removeRowMethod}"/>
          </apex:pageBlockButtons>
      <apex:pageBlockSection title="Information" columns="1">
          <apex:inputText value="{!Registration.FirstName__c}"/>
          <apex:inputText value="{!Registration.LastName__c}"/>
          <apex:inputText value="{!Registration.ContactNumber__c}"/>
      </apex:pageBlockSection>
  </apex:pageBlock>
  </apex:form>
</apex:page>



The controller code

public class Reg {

    public String Registration { get; set; }

    public PageReference removeRowMethod() {
        return null;
    }


    public PageReference addRowMethod() {
        return null;
    }


    public PageReference Cancel() {
        return null;
    }


    public PageReference Save() {
        return null;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

`public String Registration { get; set; }` - this is a String variable. A "primitive" like Integer or Boolean. It doesn't have fields.

You either make it an sObject (no idea what you're doing, do these fields exist on say standard `Contact` object or do you have a custom `Registration__c`), say

```
public Registration__c registration {get;set;}
// ...
// constructor
public Reg(){
    registration = new Registration__c(LastName__c = 'Hello there');
}
```

Or you could have three free-floating string fields in the class and then just reference them on VF page.

```
public String firstName {get;set;}
public String lastName{get;set;}
public String contactNumber {get;set;}

<apex:inputText label="First Name" value="{!firstName}" />
```